# Surjective function in topology

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Let $(X, \tau)$ be a compact space and surjective function $f: X \rightarrow (0, \infty) $ (where $(0, \infty)$ is respect to the euclidean topology). Show that this function is continuous. If not, point the counterexample.

I have a big problem finding this surjective map (function). Do I have to find it? Or can I prove it in another way.

I will be grateful for any hint :)

Comment: There is no such continuous function. What do you know about the images of compact spaces under continuous functions?

Comment: To prove it, the function $f$ is given and you must prove continuity. To disprove it, you have to find such space $X$ and surjective $f$ that is not continuous.

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: @Shaun: as a kindness to the OP, you could have suggested a better title. And as a kindness to the rest of us you should have pointed out that giving the question in the title and not in the body of the question is deprecated.

Answer (score 2):

Assume there exists a continuous surjective function $f: X \to (0,\infty)$. Since $X$ is compact, the image of $f$ is compact, which by surjectivity is the whole space $(0,\infty)$.

However, $(0,\infty)$ equipped with the euclidean topology is not compact, because the cover $\mathcal U := \ \{(n,n+1)~|~ n \in \mathbb N\ \}$ has no finite subcover.

Thus we get a contradiction.